# Fatal error Out of memory fetching data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, php-ini

Hello I am facing problem with memory limit.

Please find the code below and let me guide if any thing mistake in my code.

```
function getRecords($table, $limit = '') {
    global $db;
    if (isNotEmpty($limit)) {
        $intLimit = intval($limit);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table limit $intLimit";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    }
    $sth = $db->query($sql);

    return $sth->fetchAll();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: don't use `*` if you don't need `all the columns`.

Comment: Modify your to fetch one row at a time as well instead of doing a `fetchAll`

Answer (score 1):

If your query is taking so much time then you have to work on it. Always use some optimization techniques in this case:

- Never use `SELECT *`, until all column are required
- Never select all rows until required. Use LIMIT OFFSET instead

Comment: Can you edit and send me the code. It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: It,s working fine now I have set the limit 300. After this correction it is working fine.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the above rules always it will optimize the query.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Mayank I have solved this issue. I have just set the limit in this code.

Thanks All